# Method that checks if the method was already executed with that input

Tags: java, recursion, stack, catalan

```
public class CatalanNumbers {

    private int howManyVariaties;
    private int catalanNumber;
    private int catalanNumber;

    public int catalan(int a) {
       if (Method was never executed with that input) {
              howManyVariaties++;
       int catalanNumber = 0;
       for (int i= 0; i < n; i++) {
           catalanNumber += catalan(i) * catalan( n- 1 -i);
       return catalanNumber
```

To sum it up I only want to check how the maximum stack depth is.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Add a Set to your class that keeps track of what input was used and check that set inside the method

```
public class CatalanNumbers {

    private int howManyVariaties;
    private int catalanNumber;
    private int catalanNumber;
    private Set<Integer> alreadyHandled = new HashSet<>();

    public int catalan(int a) {
        if (alreadyHandled.add(a)) {                  
            //rest of code
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Why adding linear complexity? Prefer ‘HashSet<Integer>’ in given solution

Comment: I would suggest using Set instead of List. It will avoid duplicate elements.

Comment: The problem is rather in contains() that takes O(n) instead of O(1), but anyway Set is more essential choice here :)

Comment: @YuriiJ You are correct, I will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have not expressed it properly. @YuriiJ said it perfectly.